# Change background color and back on unhover

Tags: jquery, css

I use this script to change background-color of .entry-content after hover on div. How to back to default background color of .entry-content when the div is not hovered.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.mydiv').hover(function(){
      $('article#post-570 .entry-content').css({'background-color':'#80ddff','transition':'2s'});
    });
 });
```

Comment: why don't use css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for that is:

```
$('yourSelector').hover(
  function() {
    //do something for Hover
  }, function() {
    //do something for unHover
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use JQuery, you can use `mouseout`.

```
$(".mydiv").mouseout(function(){
  $("article#post-570 .entry-content").css("background-color", "gray");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   <style>
        .afterHove {
            background-color: #80ddff;
            transition: 2s
        }
      
    </style>

       <div class="myDiv">Hello div</div>
<div class="entry-content">
    default color
</div>
   

     <script>
        

 $().ready(function () {
        $('.myDiv').hover(function () {
            console.log('hello')
            $('.entry-content').toggleClass('afterHove');
        });
    });
        </script>
```